# On-premise deployment of mesibo

Tags: mesibo

1. What is the support plan for on-premise deployment?
2. Does on-premise deployment need communication with outside private networks?
3. How does multi-tenancy work within an application? (Do not want to show users of one client to another client)
4. What is the expiry period of the token generated for the user?
5. What is the access level for user token? Would the user be able to fetch everything or is it limited to fetch the user's own conversations?